# Spring boot Webclient metrics not exposing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, metrics

I am using spring boot & spring webflux version 3.1.4
I have written the below code for Webclient.

```
return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(endpoint)
                .defaultHeader("api-key", apiKey)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build();
```

And also have added dependency for micrometer Prometheus.

```
implementation ('io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.10.5')
```

Here the management code for actuator

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /
      exposure:
        include: health,info,prometheus,beans,metrics
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
      path-mapping:
        prometheus: metrics
        metrics: metrics-info
    metrics:
      export:
        prometheus:
          enabled: true
```

But when I go to /metrics-info endpoint I am not seeing the metrics for webclient.
It says in [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.M1/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-metrics-http-clients) document that it is by default exposed but I am not able to see on the endpoint as well as on prometheus endpoint.

Do I need to add any other metrics configs for exposing http.client.requests which is by default exposed ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer would be to make the webclient object using Builder
Here is the example for it :

```
@Bean
    public WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        return webClientBuilder
                .baseUrl(endpoint)
                .defaultHeader("api-key", apiKey)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .bu
```